# Is it possible to get all pieces of art without visiting other towns?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

My art gallery in the museum is only about half-full. For about two months now, whenever Redd comes he only has paintings and statues I already have, even if they're forgeries (in other words, I haven't even seen a forgery whose original isn't already in my museum).

I remember a villager saying that some objects don't appear in all towns. Does this apply to art? Is it impossible to fill your museum's art gallery without buying from Redd in another town?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I just got the last piece of art I was missing, and have never bought art from another town (or even visited one, except in dreams).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can get all paintings from Redd

Source: [Animal crossing wiki](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Painting)

> In Animal Crossing: New Leaf, 26 paintings can be obtained. In the
>   game, the ability to identify fakes before sale was added, with forged
>   paintings showing distinct differences to their real, authentic
>   versions, using the new swivel camera function.
>
> **All paintings can be purchased from Crazy Redd's for 3,920 bells** and
>   sold for 490 bells. Villagers also give out paintings as presents,
>   particularly smug villagers. However, there is no way to authenticate
>   until after the sale.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to contradict the idea that some of them won't appear in a certain town.